# Right way to convert 120VAC to 5V?

Tags: power

I am currently using a Particle Photon to control a relay that turns a lamp on and off. I would like to power the Photon and the lamp from the same power cord.

Currently, I have a power cord for the lamp and I am also using a usb cable to power the Photon.

I found [this (Enclosed AC DC Converter)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/BP5038A1/BP5038A1-ND/756609) and I am wondering if this will work if I split the 120V power cord to go to the relay and the converter. Will I need anything else? Are there any other concerns I should worry about? Do I need to worry about polarity?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the datasheets for any electronics because they have an incredible amount of information.

**Short Answer, No**

If you read the [datasheet for the Particle Photon](https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/photon-datasheet/), it recommends no less than a 1A power supply. Unfortunately, the [datasheet for the AC/DC Converter](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/module/power_module/acdc_converter/bp5038a1.pdf) you found shows it has a maximum output current of 30mA, which is nearly 30x smaller than you would want for the Photon.

**How to Make This Work**

Because you're trying to get ~1A @ 5V and you're working with 120VAC, you don't have to reinvent the wheel--or in this case, the USB Charger Brick!

Literally any off-the-shelf USB charging brick for a phone or tablet will work. I can't think of any that are less than 1A-rated anymore, but if you want a hobbyist-level supply, something like [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/501?gclid=Cj0KEQiA0L_FBRDMmaCTw5nxm-ABEiQABn-VqbbpG3K3rVPtn01mbKr3J9tlkb8CP5K8yCYrUjuRFNMaAv_T8P8HAQ) may be right for you (not to plug for Adafruit, though they are a great learning resource).

Basically, you'll have a box that houses the Photon and the relay. You simply put this in the box with it, and voila! you have 5V power for the Photon.

**Bonus Points**

You can even go nuts and remove the device from its housing (DISCLAIMER: This may void the UL listing and any warranty) and just grab the innards to package neatly in a nice enclosure.

EDIT:

**Easiest Solution**
Just install one of [these](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/aplusautomation/vendorimages/bf5475b0-12da-4b13-a9e2-94a9fc27e1ce.jpg._CB311932683__SL300__.jpg) at the receptacle you intend to use.

Comment: Where did you get the 1A value from? The recommended conditions table on the datasheet you have linked mentions Avg Operating Current to be 80-100mA.  1A is mentioned in absolute maximum ratings, which I think defines a safe limit.

Comment: Under the "Power" section of the linked documentation, it says typical operating current is 80mA (still above the AC/DC the OP asked about), but the author recommends, "[...] the power source should be sufficient enough to source 1A of current to be on the safe side." Given the OP is asking this question, I doubt the OP is likely to calculate their exact power needs, so going with the manufacturer recommendation seems wise. Also, with WiFi, peak current goes as high as ~400mA.

Comment: You've also got options like these [DC 5V 2A Switching Power Supply Board Converter Transformer](http://www.banggood.com/DC-5V-2A-Switching-Power-Supply-Board-Converter-Transformer-p-1013495.html?rmmds=search) since anyway you have to put your mains relay in an enclosed box.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't even look at how many amps this gives off. After looking at the Particle Photon data sheet it says that it operates at a peak of 430mA so you are right this wouldn't work. Im not trying to use a usb block because I want to keep the size down. Also this is more of an exercise for me to learn more about how things work. Unfortunately, Im teaching myself via internet resources so I'm bound to make stupid mistakes.

Comment: As someone who does this semi-regularly, I'd simply gut an off-the-shelf component and throw it in my enclosure. There are times when it's worth reengineering something, but this really isn't one of those times. If it is to you, I'd recommend going full-on and building a transformer-rectifier-SMPS system. *That* will really teach you something.

Comment: Also, the USB power brick can be in your enclosure too.